# WordPress ReAuth =1 Loop with wpCAS

Tags: plugins, login, authentication

The **wpCAS plugin** appears to be working: I have a **subdomain** on a website which contains the **WordPress** installation (i.e. `test.mywebsite.com`), and I'm running through a **WordPress GitHub Repo** along with **Capistrano** for actual deployment. This is important because, due to this setup, the content is within a subdirectory, i.e. `test.mywebsite.com/wp`. The result is that, in order to access the site's admin section, I have to input `test.mywebsite.com/wp/wp-admin` in my browser. Accessing the frontend website, however, only requires that I input `test.website.com`. Confusing enough?

I'm testing all of this with a **localhost MAMP server**. It should also be worth nothing that I have also redirected the IP of `test.mywebsite.com` to my local box via my Mac's `hosts` file, so everything is correctly taking place on the local box.

Now, here's the catch: I'm using the wpCAS plugin with a **RubyCAS server**. Everything works up until the actual login process.

wpCAS is designed to simply **re-direct the login page to my CAS login**, and then **match the credentials** typed into the CAS interface with those in WordPress's database. If there's a match, it (theoretically) would bring me to the admin page with my credentials logged in and working correctly.

As a result of this setup, my typing in `localhost/wp/wp-admin` takes me to `auth.mywebsite.com`, the CAS interface where I can input my credentials.

However, once I put my credentials into the CAS interface I'm instead hit with a **redirect loop** that looks like:

`wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

and

`wp-admin/`

so around and around we go!

Any idea why this would happen and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Within the `wpcas.php` file inside of the `wpCAS` plugin folder, lines 85-123 detail the actual login function of **wpCAS**. **Lines 104** & **108** detail specifically on how wpCAS redirects you to the admin page:

**104**:

```
wp_redirect( preg_match( '/^http/', $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ? $_GET['redirect_to'] : site_url( $_GET['redirect_to'] ));
```

**108**:

```
wp_redirect( site_url( '/wp-admin/' ));
```

However, this results (for reasons unknown to me) in a redirect loop of ***[DOOM](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/)***. Thanks to [this tip](http://maisonbisson.com/projects/wpcas/comment-page-1/#comment-246162), however (many thanks to Mr. Luigi Balzano), I found a solution. Change the `wp_redirect` functions on these two lines to `wp_safe_redirect`, like so:

**104**:

```
wp_safe_redirect( preg_match( '/^http/', $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ? $_GET['redirect_to'] : site_url( $_GET['redirect_to'] ));
```

**108**:

```
wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/wp-admin/' ));
```

This kicked me out of the redirect loop of ***[DOOM](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/)***.

The plugin, despite being two years old, still works beautifully with **WordPress** version 3.5.1 and below.

Hope this helps you wpCAS vagrants!